# Querying Sqlite database in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-datepicker, android-query

Thish code work fine for me it show the information of every employee one by one.
BUT i want to see only the information of the one employee of given id.
how can i do that .

```
c=myDbHelper.query("EMP_TABLE", null, null, null, null,null, null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()) 
        {
            do {

                Toast.makeText(CopyDbActivity.this,
                        "_id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                        "E_NAME: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                        "E_AGE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                        "E_DEPT:  " + c.getString(3),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a getRecord method in your Sqlite helper class

```
public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException
   {
   Cursor cursor = db.query(EMP_TABLE, new String[] { _id,
            E_NAME, E_AGE,E_DEPT }, _id + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(rowId) }, null, null, null, null);
   if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    }
   return mCursor;
    }
```

Then

```
   db.open(); 
   Cursor c = db.getRecord(1); // pass the record id
   Toast.makeText(CopyDbActivity.this,
                    "_id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                    "E_NAME: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                    "E_AGE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                    "E_DEPT:  " + c.getString(3),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The third and fourth parameters of the [`SQLiteDatabase query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method can be used to form a SQL `WHERE` clause.

For example, to get all rows with where `_id` is 2:

```
String[] selectionArgs = {"2"};
c=myDbHelper.query("EMP_TABLE", null, "_id=?", selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```